# How to loop over a Tree widget when the depth of the node is unknown (GWT)?

Tags: gwt, loops, tree, widget

I searched over the internet but didn't see any single post discussing about this very useful topic. Here is my problem.

I got a Tree that has CheckBoxes on the root & on the child of the TreeItem.

I want that when users check on the root CheckBox of the TreeItem, then all the child CheckBox & the sub-root checkBox were checked.

For example, look at this picture.
[image: CheckBox Tree]

I want that when the user select "Level 1" CheckBox then "Level 11" & "Level 111" & "Level 112" checkboxes were checked. When user deselect "Level 1" CheckBox then "Level 11" & "Level 111" & "Level 112" checkboxes were unchecked.

When users check the "Main" then all its children ("Level 1", "Level 11", "Level 111" & "Level 112", "Level 2", "Level 21") got checked. When users uncheck "Main" then it will uncheck all its children.

However, when users check "Level 2" then only "Level 21" was checked.

**Note**: The depth of the Tree is unknown in advanced.

This is Data code:

```
Tree myTree=new Tree();
TreeItem item1=new TreeItem(new CheckBox("Main"));
myTree.addItem(item1);
TreeItem item2=new TreeItem(new CheckBox("Level 1"));
item1.addItem(item2);
TreeItem item3=new TreeItem(new CheckBox("Level 11"));
item2.addItem(item3);
item3.addItem(new CheckBox("Level 111"));
item3.addItem(new CheckBox("Level 112"));

TreeItem item6=new TreeItem(new CheckBox("Level 2"));
item6.addItem(new CheckBox("Level 21"));
item1.addItem(item6);
```

This is the code I researched but it only goes to 1 level

```
   Iterator<Widget> widgetsOfTree=myTree.iterator();

   TreeItem myTreeItem=myTree.getItem(0);
   for (int c=0; c<myTreeItem.getChildCount(); c++){
        TreeItem childTreeItem=myTreeItem.getChild(c);
        CheckBox myCheckBox=(CheckBox)childTreeItem.getWidget();
    }
```

This is the additional code that was based on the traverseTree method provided by 
Mayank Pandya. This code works when i click the "Main" or "Level 1" or "Level 2" CheckBox, but it didn't work properly when i click other checkboxes. For example, when clicking "Level 11" nothing got selected.

```
 myCheckBox.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {


            for(int i=0; i<myTree.getItemCount(); i++){
                TreeItem myTreeItem = myTree.getItem(i); 

                for (int c=0; c<myTreeItem.getChildCount(); c++){
                    TreeItem categoryTreeItem=myTreeItem.getChild(c);
                    CheckBox subCB=(CheckBox)categoryTreeItem.getWidget();

                    if(myCheckBox==subCB){

                        traverseTree(categoryTreeItem, myCheckBox.isChecked()) ;
                    }
                }


            }
  }

  });
```

I believe many people is looking for this question & hope my question can help many others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this kind of recursive function for traverse tree.

```
public void traverseTree(TreeItem item, Boolean checkValue) 
{    for(int i = 0; i < item.getChildCount(); i++) 
     {    

          // do action here 
          TreeItem childTreeItem=item.getChild(i);
          CheckBox myCheckBox=(CheckBox)childTreeItem.getWidget();
          myCheckBox.setChecked(checkValue);

          // recursive call for current node.
          traverseTree(childTreeItem,checkValue); 
     } 
}
```

As per your code you can use.

```
myCheckBox.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

        for(int i=0; i<myTree.getItemCount(); i++){
            TreeItem myTreeItem = myTree.getItem(i); 
            CheckBox subCB=(CheckBox)myTreeItem.getWidget();

            if(myCheckBox==subCB){
                traverseTree(myTreeItem, myCheckBox.isChecked()) ;
            }
        }
   }
```

});

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for your help, but when users click on a Checkbox then how can we identify which TreeItem this Checkbox belongs to?

Comment: I have just editted my question to include code that is based on your traverseTree method. Pls have a look to see anything wrong?

Comment: I think we need to use some Recursive solutions to identify the TreeItem that a Checkbox belongs to

Comment: it only works when i click on "Main", it didn't work when i click other checkboxes

Comment: when we use "item.getChildCount()" & "TreeItem myTreeItem = myTree.getItem(i);", it only goes to 1 level. If we want to go to next level we have to loop myTreeItem.getChildCount() & so on. So it is kind of recursive.

Comment: @ Mayank Pandya, thank you very much for your help, finally I fixed.